# Problems connection to localhost database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

This is probably an easy one. But it's been a while since I accessed a database and I look it up at W3School. I went for the object-oriented way as i love OO.
The problem is, I don't recall having to create a user or anything like that to be able to access my databases.

shouldn't this work fine?

```
$ip = "localhost";
$user = ""; //I have tried "username" also
$password = ""; //I have tried "password" also
$dbName = "my_database_test";

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($ip, $user, $password, $dbName);
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
```

All i get is an error saying:

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Comment: I was looking around the privliges in myPhpAdmin and saw that all localhost connections had auto-generated user for "root" so i passed "root" in the $user and "" in the $password and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of username, password or ip is incorrect.
Find username and password on the server.
If you use in localhost (in your pc) username is "root" and password is blank or set in installation time.